# Согласование определения с однородными членами в разных формах числа

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование, однородные-члены, определения

*...где хорошие зарплаты и карьерный рост.*

Здесь "хорошие" относится и к зарплатам, и к карьерному росту. Ясно ли это из контекста или лучше перестроить предложение?

Я знаю, что такой вариант возможен:

*в своем изложении и выводах...* (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)

По смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схема такой конструкции: <прил. во мн. ч.> <сущ. во мн. ч.> и <сущ. в ед. ч.>.
Вопрос фактически о том, как такая конструкция будет понята читателем, отнесет ли он прилагательное ко второму существительному. Не знаю, есть ли правило на этот счет, но думаю, что носитель языка воспринимает текст интуитивно, а не листает справочник после прочтения каждого предложения. А интуиция говорит мне, что прил. во мн. ч. относится **только** к сущ. во мн. ч.

> хорошие зарплаты и карьерный рост

В данном предложении зарплаты — хорошие, а возможность карьерного роста — само по себе положительное явление, определение "хороший" ничего к нему не добавило бы.

Answer (score 1):

***...где хорошие зарплаты и карьерный рост.***

Не поняла, в чём сомнение. Допустимо ли соседство существительных множественного и единственного числа или согласование во множественном числе? Соседство возможно. Определение стоит рядом с существительным множ.числа, так что в единственном его уже не поставишь.

Но мне был бы ближе вариант**..*.где хорошая зарплата и карьерный рост*.**   Зависит от смысла: что интересует - зарплата для говорящего или вообще зарплаты на предприятии.

Comment: Сомнение в том, что я хочу передать, что "хорошие" относится и к "карьерному росту" тоже, однако второй однородный член стоит в единственном числе? Может ли на него распространяться значение определения, или необходимо перестраивать предложение?

Answer (score 1):

лучше написать так: **..где хорошая зарплата и быстрый  карьерный рост.**

Можно написать "хорошие зарплаты", но это разговорное выражение, в отличие от карьерного роста (получается несочетаемость).

**Хорошие зарплаты и карьерный рост:** прилагательное скорее относится к первому существительному. Выражение "хороший карьерный рост"  не слишком популярно.

Примеры:

Еще **большие зарплаты и льготы** ожидают тех, кто не побоится испытать себя в практически фронтовых условиях. [Виктор Градов. Иди и служи // «Ежедневные новости» (Владивосток), 2003]

Все они сулили избирателям одно и то же: **большие зарплаты и пенсии**, дешевые квартиры, бесплатную медицину, борьбу с коррупцией и порядок. [Владимир Войнович. 2000]

Comment: В ваших примерах оба существительных стоят во множественном числе. А есть ли примеры, схожие с моим предложением, чтобы бы определение стояло во множественном числе и относилось к обоим однородным членам, второе из которых выражено существительным в единственном числе?

Comment: Пример можно придумать, например: На участке росли молодые сосны и береза. Но здесь прилагательное во мн. числе читатель отнесет  к первому существительному, а если это не так, то автор должен перестроить предложение.  Эта тема разбирается подробно у Розенталя http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05, но вашего примера там  нет (вроде бы). И скорее всего, таких примеров вообще не существует.